# Positioning flex box divs within a container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this https://jsfiddle.net/zd2Lpkor/ flex box based code that i am trying to understand how i can position elements using flexbox.

[image]

In my fiddle, i set up a width of 1px but the code produces a div that isn't 1px in width. Why is that happening?

Secondly if i lay out my divs like this

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div style="flex-grow: 1">1</div>
  <div style="flex-grow: 1">2</div>
  <div style="flex-grow: 8">3</div>
</div>
```

can i use flexbox to position my div in any marked spot in the diagram below?. Iam looking for flex box features that can allow me place my div or content in exact cells that i pick within my diagram below.

Comment: *"i set up a width of 1px but the code produces a div that isn't 1px in width. Why is that happening?"* Because you have `flex-grow` applied to each item via inline styles.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin So `flex-grow` has a default minimum width?

Comment: No. `flex-grow` tells the item to consume free space on the line, based on the available space and the value you set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to position specific div in specific cell in your layout you should consider CSS Grid instead of flexbox:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/grid

This allows you to create a definition of layout of your cells, and assign divs to chosen areas. You do it with `grid-template-areas` in **container element**. You have to also use `display: grid`. It could be similar to (`x*` are areas that you want to be empty, but still they have to be defined in layout):

```
grid-template-areas: "1  x  x  x  x  2"
                     "B1 x  x  x  x  B2"
                     "C1 x1 M1 x2 x2 C2";
                     "x3 x3 M2 x2 x2 x4";
                     "L1 x5 x5 x5 x5 L2";
                     "3  x5 x5 x5 x5 4";
```

Then you can assign div to one of the areas:

```
grid-area: B1;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Tomasz's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14849912/tomasz) answer is correct, but if you want to work with flex box you can do it like this.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
}

.row {
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: black;
}

.one,
.two,
.three,
.four,
.five,
.six
{
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.four {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row one">
    <h5>1</h5>
    <h5>2</h5>
  </div>

  <div class="row two">
    <h5>b1</h5>
    <h5>b2</h5>
  </div>

  <div class="row three">
    <h5>c1</h5>
    <h5>m1</h5>
    <h5>c2</h5>
  </div>

  <div class="row four">
    <h5>m2</h5>
  </div>

  <div class="row five">
    <h5>l1</h5>
    <h5>l2</h5>
  </div>

  <div class="row six">
    <h5>3</h5>
    <h5>4</h5>
  </div>

</div>
```

Also if you want to learn CSS flexbox I recommend [this site](https://www.internetingishard.com/html-and-css/flexbox/)